# Story identification: Quantum tunnelling let everyone see anything and anywhere in the past

Tags: story-identification

<sup>Knowing my luck I'm again asking for something obvious like Harry Potter or LOTR but hey, Google hates me...</sup>

It was a story that I've read about early 2000s and the story was describing social changes in the society caused by a new way of data transmission via "quantum tunnelling".

This technology was initially developed as a mean to send information almost instantaneous over long distances and involved creating a tiny portal on the sender and receiver end, that allowed to transfer electromagnetic waves. 
Soon after, this invention has been upgraded and started allowing to see also events in the past.

Initially, this technology was held only by a giant telecommunication agency (and rented to government and press) but thanks to a leak it became widespread to population, that started using implants allowing everyone to see any events that has happened almost whenever in time: privacy, secrecy almost ceased to exist, since without much effort you could see not only your neighbour changing but also JFK having sex with Marilyn Monroe (and then see from dozen angles who actually shot him on who's order etc.). Getting away with crimes also became impossible, since police could clearly see "whodunit", although people started to commit low-level crimes (like littering) on purpose, as a strange way to annoy the ever-watching Big Brother.

One of the plots involved an old crime - father of the family of two has been convicted and executed for killing his son, while the real culprit was his mentally unstable daughter. Blaming the quantum tunnelling inventor for the loss of her whole family (because he didn't invent it before the execution and because review of the crime found the real murderer) wife of the executed guy starts plotting to kill him.

This book must have been written some time post cold-war era, I remember that it mentions Russia (not USSR) and the Internet

Comment: This is not the answer you are looking for, but the plot seems to have many similarities to Asimov's [The Dead Past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dead_Past)

Comment: The book was more modern - I'm fairly sure it was mentioning Internet and Russia (not USSR)

Comment: [The Light of Other Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_of_Other_Days) seems  to fit the timeframe and general concept, though I see no murder plot.

Comment: @Mwr247 thats it! The murder plot is simply not mentioned in wiki.

Comment: Note that proposed duplicate target is already the target of several other closed duplicates.

Comment: You've found your answer, but there's also a technology similar to this mentioned briefly in Childhood's End by Arthur C. Clarke.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering your mention of multiple plots going, as well as the time frame you gave for your reading, it sounds like [The Light of Other Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_of_Other_Days) by Arthur C. Clarke and Stephen Baxter. It features a time viewer invention originally intended for data transmission, that is released to the world and greatly affects society as we know it.

Comment: This answer brought to you by [TVTropes: Chronoscope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Chronoscope), subsection Literature (warning, tvtropes link, wasted time, all that jazz...)

Comment: @user14111 Good call, added that in.

Comment: Edited to add Baxter, who probably did more of the work than Clarke.